# How can I update form field on Microsoft CRM Online via Javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, javascript, dynamics-crm-online

I've just created a custom order form on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online.

Basically, I'd like to update Total Amount field as multiply of Quantity and Amount Field. I think I can do this via Javascripts. I just opened Quantity Field Properties menu and reach Events menu. It requires to select a js library and write right function. I'm quite sure it's too much easy, however, I do not know how to do.

Basically:

Update Amount Field X Quantity Field should be = Total Amount Field value. My script should run on Quantity Field on Change event.

Comment: Where have you looked to resolve this very basic question? could Google not help you?

Comment: Hi Greg, Yes It's very basic question. Google no. Even I can't find how to put right code on the Field's Event's menu. I think my problem is just putting code on the Field's Event's menu on right way,

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a jerk (sorry that I do). Generally it helps to state what you've done to try and resolve the issue yourself. If you've found the SDK (no idea if you have...?) then state if you can't understand it or can't find the right topic or whatever... Your question implies that you've come to CRM, couldn't understand it so posted here for someone else to do the legwork. We can only go by what you post in your question and it sounded like you'd not tried anything.  Anyway, I've added an answer which hopefully will help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is info on how to setup the javascript for your forms: [microsoft's form programming reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261.aspx)

the code for your calculation will look something like this:

```
var amount = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("youramountfieldname").getValue();
var quantity = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourquantityfieldname").getValue();

var totalamount = amount * quantity;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourtotalamountfieldname").setValue(totalamount);
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for your answer. I'm quite sure your code is more probably correct. However, i couldn't add your code on the related field via Customization menu.. Do you have email address? I'd like to send screenshots where I've been trying to put codes and how. I think you'll see my mistake at first glance..

Comment: See Greg's answer, it has the additional information you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. The code needs tobe encapsulated as a JS function and then needs to be created as a [Web Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473)
2. The web resource needs to be associated with your form
3. You can then assign a function name to the appropriate event handler within your form.

Useful walkthrough: http://ayazahmad.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/javascript-libraries-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/