# Where does one enter the JavaScript code in CRM Dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I update form field on Microsoft CRM Online via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922319/how-can-i-update-form-field-on-microsoft-crm-online-via-javascript)

I've started to play with CRM Dynamics yesterday so this question should be seen as a **very** basic one. I've been coding for many years but CRM D is news to me.

Apparently, one is supposed to be able to enter JavaScript code to customize the behavior of the application. I've understood that there's an API for that and that touching DOM directly or playing with jQuery is a no-no.

Question: Where is the JS-code supposed to be entered? I've gone through all the menus but as far I can see, there's no spot where I could plug-in my custom code.

E.g.: Where do I get to define a validation for the last name of a contact currently being defined?

Answer (score 2):

So I would suggest checking out these articles.

This ones gives a general overview of JavaScript in Crm - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx).

You are probably going to most commonly use JavaScript on the form - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261).

Also check out this [tutorial](http://blog.webfortis.com/post/2011/08/15/A-Brief-Introduction-to-CRM-2011-JavaScript.aspx) which explains how to use form events and libraries. This [tutorial](http://blog.webfortis.com/post/2012/02/28/CRM-2011-JavaScript-Tutorial-01-Basic-Field-Calculation.aspx) in the same series gives a basic example.

You are allowed to use jQuery in some circumstances as described here - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261#BKMK_UsingjQuery).

Comment: Great links but I've got them already.   :)       My issue is **far** more basic. I've found the spot where one can connect to different pre-existing code. I've found the custom code (e.g. check for last name validation) and I believe I can edit that code as well. What I didn't have (yet) is a way to "shove in" the JS function I've written in Notepad. Let's say it's called "function checkFirstName(){ ... } - how do I "learn" CRM Dynamics to see it?

Comment: I'm slighty confused, why are you putting the code in notepad? Do you mean the text entry field of crm?

Comment: I was unclear, I realize. I'm typing the code in Notepad at the moment because all I need is a small function doing `alert("hazaa!");`. Later on I'll do my coding elsewhere (VS, probably). The issue I have (had?) is that I'm (was?) unclear on where to put the code. I believe that I've found a way to add a resource and code in it now, though. So, the questions is really about where to paste in the JS code so the CRM will "see" it.

Comment: You need to add a web resource to crm with the javascript in, then you add an event handler which calls your function on the form. This is described in the second tutorial link.

Answer (score 2):

To enter the JavaScript first upload it as a web resource. Then if you want it to fire for example on load of the form, go to the form customization, Form Properties:
[image]

From there a menu should pop up:
[image]

In the Form Libraries add the Java web resource. In the Event Handlers select the Javascript you are using and the function name. Hope this helps :) Gdluck